# number of different substrings of S which contain the character X at least once

Tags: c++, string

You have a string S with length N and one character X. Find the number of different substrings of S which contain the character X at least once.

INPUT: abcabc c 
OUTPUT:15
here 'c' is the character.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: And [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find `count_total_substring` of the S string by `N*(N+1)/2` formula.

Then slice/split the string with the X character. Then we get an array of token substrings of the S string which excludes the search character. Now apply

```
substring_count=length*(length+1)/2
```

formula to each of these substrings. Sum all of the substring counts. Sum result is the count of all substrings those don't contain any X character, lets call it count_not_present.

Now the result should be = `count_total_substring - count_not_present.`

```
        int c=0, i, notPresent=0;

        int totalSubstring = N * (N+1) / 2;

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if(S.charAt(i) == search) {
                notPresent += (c * (c+1) / 2);
                c = 0;
            }
            else {
                c++;
            }
        }

        notPresent += (c * (c+1) / 2);
        result = totalSubstring - notPresent;
        System.out.println(result);
```

This is as far I could found. Please check if any case is missing from this logic.

Comment: What is srcStr? Can you please tell?

Comment: The input string. According to your question, it is "abcabc"

Comment: Welcome! I edited my answer symbols according to your question. It would be better understandable now, I hope. Please up vote the answer.